# Dynamic display using Flutter and PHP

Tags: php, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Hi guys I'm new in flutter. Please help me to solve by problem

I want to create a display using parse json on php url result And defined the result on final blockBustorDealList.

I am looking for a solution for this code.
I've provided the entire code below.

I just want a result like

```
final blockBustorDealList = [
  {
    'image':
        'https://is.simplify.cool/component/admin/upload_img/demo/backend/files/thumbnail/NEC56049_thumbnail.webp?v=20220602014017',
    'title': 'Trick R Treat Ultimate Sam',
    'offer': 'RMB 54.90'
  },
  {
    'image':
        'https://is.simplify.cool/component/admin/upload_img/demo/backend/files/thumbnail/NEC61901_thumbnail.webp?v=20220602014017',
    'title': 'Blockbustor Deals On TVs',
    'offer': 'From ₹5,499'
  },
  {
    'image':
        'https://is.simplify.cool/component/admin/upload_img/demo/backend/files/thumbnail/NEC54206_thumbnail.webp?v=20220602014017',
    'title': 'Asian, Kraasa & more',
    'offer': 'Min. 55% Off'
  },
  {
    'image':
        'https://is.simplify.cool/component/admin/upload_img/demo/backend/files/thumbnail/NEC54226_thumbnail.webp?v=20220602014017',
    'title': 'Puma, FILA & more',
    'offer': 'Min. 60% Off'
  }
];
```

using the result of http://192.168.1.4/flutter/get_products.php url

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

// My Own Imports
import 'package:go_kart/pages/category/top_offers.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class BlockBusterDeals extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          // TopImage(),
          OfferGrid(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

final blockBustorDealList = [
  {
    'image':
        'https://is.simplify.cool/component/admin/upload_img/demo/backend/files/thumbnail/NEC56049_thumbnail.webp?v=20220602014017',
    'title': 'Trick R Treat Ultimate Sam',
    'offer': 'RMB 54.90'
  },
  {
    'image':
        'https://is.simplify.cool/component/admin/upload_img/demo/backend/files/thumbnail/NEC61901_thumbnail.webp?v=20220602014017',
    'title': 'Blockbustor Deals On TVs',
    'offer': 'From ₹5,499'
  },
  {
    'image':
        'https://is.simplify.cool/component/admin/upload_img/demo/backend/files/thumbnail/NEC54206_thumbnail.webp?v=20220602014017',
    'title': 'Asian, Kraasa & more',
    'offer': 'Min. 55% Off'
  },
  {
    'image':
        'https://is.simplify.cool/component/admin/upload_img/demo/backend/files/thumbnail/NEC54226_thumbnail.webp?v=20220602014017',
    'title': 'Puma, FILA & more',
    'offer': 'Min. 60% Off'
  }
];

class OfferGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  // var url = "http://192.168.1.4/flutter/get_products.php";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    InkWell getStructuredGridCell(blockBustorDeal) {
      final item = blockBustorDeal;
      return InkWell(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 13, 13),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
                height: 170.0,
                child: Image.network(
                  item['image'],
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                // alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      '${item['title']}',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '${item['offer']}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: const Color(0xFF67A86B), fontSize: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => TopOffers(title: '${item['title']}')),
          );
        },
      );
    }

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          width: width,
          height: 479.0,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: width,
                height: 460.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, right: 5.0, left: 5.0),
                width: width - 20.0,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0, left: 10.0, top: 10.0),
                child: GridView.count(
                  primary: false,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 0,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 0,
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  childAspectRatio: ((width) / 500),
                  children: List.generate(blockBustorDealList.length, (index) {
                    return getStructuredGridCell(blockBustorDealList[index]);
                  }),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

- version: 1.0.0+1
- sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

Comment: what do you want explain in details

Comment: I just want to define blockBustorDealList using the "http://192.168.1.4/flutter/get_products.php" result

Comment: where is the response of above url?

Comment: I don't have yet

Comment: It is static for now

Comment: is this `blockBustorDealList`  your json response

Comment: you want to display `blockBustorDealList` string inside widget?

Comment: Yes sir, I want blockBustorDealList as json response

Comment: Unless your issue is with the PHP code you're calling (which you then need to add and explain the issue), please remove that tag. If the data from the URL is correct, then it's irrelevant which language created it. Your question will also be more focused if you remove tags that aren't relevant to your issue. People here subscribe to different tags. If you add irrelevant tags, they will just be frustrated when the issue isn't about that at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code.

Your `JSON` string :

```
List blockBustorDealList = [
    {
      'image':
          'https://is.simplify.cool/component/admin/upload_img/demo/backend/files/thumbnail/NEC56049_thumbnail.webp?v=20220602014017',
      'title': 'Trick R Treat Ultimate Sam',
      'offer': 'RMB 54.90'
    },
    {
      'image':
          'https://is.simplify.cool/component/admin/upload_img/demo/backend/files/thumbnail/NEC61901_thumbnail.webp?v=20220602014017',
      'title': 'Blockbustor Deals On TVs',
      'offer': 'From ₹5,499'
    },
    {
      'image':
          'https://is.simplify.cool/component/admin/upload_img/demo/backend/files/thumbnail/NEC54206_thumbnail.webp?v=20220602014017',
      'title': 'Asian, Kraasa & more',
      'offer': 'Min. 55% Off'
    },
    {
      'image':
          'https://is.simplify.cool/component/admin/upload_img/demo/backend/files/thumbnail/NEC54226_thumbnail.webp?v=20220602014017',
      'title': 'Puma, FILA & more',
      'offer': 'Min. 60% Off'
    }
  ];
```

Your Widget:

```
GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      ),
      itemCount: blockBustorDealList.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Card(
          elevation: 5,
          shadowColor: Colors.grey,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
              20,
            ),
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: Container(
            height: 300,
            width: 200,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(
                          10,
                        ),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(
                          10,
                        ),
                      ),
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        image: NetworkImage(
                          blockBustorDealList[index]['image'],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 2,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 80,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        blockBustorDealList[index]['title'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 15,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        blockBustorDealList[index]['offer'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          fontSize: 12,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
```

Your Result Screen:

[image]

#### Updated Answer

Add `http: ^0.13.4`  dependency/package in your `pubspec.yaml` file, refer [**`http`**](https://pub.dev/packages/http)

Import below libraries in your code:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
```

**Your API Call function**:

```
   Future<List<dynamic>> getJobsData() async {
    String url = 'https://is.simplify.cool/flutter/products.php';
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    });
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
```

Your Widget:

```
 FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
    future: getJobsData(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: GridView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,//add this line
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
            ),
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              var title = snapshot.data[index]['title'];
              var image = snapshot.data[index]['image'];
              var offer = snapshot.data[index]['offer'];

              return Card(
                elevation: 5,
                shadowColor: Colors.grey,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                    20,
                  ),
                ),
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: Container(
                  height: 300,
                  width: 200,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(
                                10,
                              ),
                              topRight: Radius.circular(
                                10,
                              ),
                            ),
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              image: NetworkImage(
                                image,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 2,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 80,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              title,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 15,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 5,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              offer,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                fontSize: 12,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      }
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    },
  ),
```

Result screen:

[image]

Comment: I just want a json response from http://192.168.1.4/flutter/get_products.php which is output is json_encode format  and the output same like blockBustorDealList

Comment: This url get not any data it gives _this side can't be reached_

Comment: please check this one https://is.simplify.cool/flutter/products.php

Comment: you want to put above string in widget?

Comment: @Gelo check my updated answer

Comment: I receive an error like this
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#8b144 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Comment: @Gelo Try to add `shrinkWrap: true,` inside `GridView`, check my updated code

Comment: Already solved Thanks a lot bro