# How to gridview item height make dynamic in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, sliver-grid

I'm starting to learn the flutter language and I want to display the product list in GridView. But there is one problem that arises.
When I run the app GridView items are displayed perfectly like the below image.

[image: Without bottom overflow error]

- But when I close the app and open it again (note without the run) then I got a bottom overflow error. The image is below.

[image]

- My Code is this

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    loadData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          "Catalog App",
        ),
      ),
      body: (CatalogModel.products != null && CatalogModel.products!.isNotEmpty)
          ? Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
              child: GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                      (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.06),
                ),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  CatalogItem item = CatalogModel.products![index];
                  return Expanded(
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  ProductDetails(item: item))),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                width: double.infinity,
                                height: 220,
                                child: Image.network(item.image,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                  child: Column(children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: double.infinity,
                                      child: Text(item.name,
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          style: GoogleFonts.cabin(
                                              fontSize: 16.0,
                                              textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              ))),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                                      child: SizedBox(
                                        width: double.infinity,
                                        child: Text(item.category,
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                            style: GoogleFonts.cabin(
                                                textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                    fontSize: 11.0,
                                                    color: Color(0xFF808080)))),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    PriceDetailsWidget(
                                        discount: item.discount,
                                        actual_price: item.actual_price,
                                        price: item.price),
                                    const AddToCartWidget(),
                                  ])),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: CatalogModel.products?.length,
              ),
            )
          : const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
      drawer: MyDrawer(),
    );
  }

  void loadData() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
    final catalogJson =
        await rootBundle.loadString("assets/files/products.json");
    final decodedData = jsonDecode(catalogJson);
    final productData = decodedData["products"];
    CatalogModel.products = List.from(productData)
        .map<CatalogItem>((item) => CatalogItem.fromMap(item))
        .toList();
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

**PriceDetailsWidget.dart**

```
class PriceDetailsWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String discount;
  final num price, actual_price;
  const PriceDetailsWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.discount,
    required this.actual_price,
    required this.price,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text("\$${price}",
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                style: GoogleFonts.cabin(
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                        decorationColor: Color(0xFF808080),
                        decorationThickness: 3.0,
                        color: Color(0xFF808080)))),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
              child: Text(
                "\$${actual_price}",
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Color(MyTheme.primaryColor),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
              child: Text(
                discount,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**AddToCartWidget.dart**

```
class AddToCartWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const AddToCartWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(elevation: 0.0, padding: EdgeInsets.zero),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: const [
          Icon(
            // <-- Icon
            CupertinoIcons.cart_fill,
            size: 24.0,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Text('Add to cart'), // <-- Text
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**CatalogModel & CatalogItem**

```
class CatalogModel {
  static List<CatalogItem>? products;
}

class CatalogItem {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String desc;
  final num price;
  final num actual_price;
  final String discount;
  final String color;
  final String image;
  final String category;
  CatalogItem(
      {required this.id,
      required this.name,
      required this.desc,
      required this.price,
      required this.actual_price,
      required this.discount,
      required this.color,
      required this.image,
      required this.category});

  factory CatalogItem.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) => CatalogItem(
      id: map["id"],
      name: map["name"],
      desc: map["desc"],
      price: map["price"],
      actual_price: map["actual_price"],
      discount: map["discount"],
      color: map["color"],
      image: map["image"],
      category: map["category"]);

  toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "desc": desc,
        "price": price,
        "color": color,
        "image": image,
      };
}
```

**products.json** this file I'm storing in the assets folder

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "id": "prod001",
            "name": "iPhone 13 Pro",
            "desc": "Your iPhone will arrive.",
            "price": 1299,
            "actual_price": 999,
            "discount": "20% off",
            "color": "#536858",
            "image": "https://d2xamzlzrdbdbn.cloudfront.net/products/66d6056e-e588-4b03-a44b-74685197003622111313.jpg",
            "category": "Mobile"
        },
        {
            "id": "prod002",
            "name": "iPhone SE (PRODUCT) RED",
            "desc": "iPhone SE (PRODUCT) RED",
            "price": 429,
            "actual_price": 399,
            "discount": "15% off",
            "color": "#A7090A",
            "image": "https://www.neolight.in/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/iPhone_XR_red.jpg",
            "category": "Mobile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It sounds to me is you use hotreload to debug your app. you may try to delete and reinstall your app see if the problem solves?

Comment: @CbL The main problem is that if we close the app and open it again then arise the problem. If I run the app from the vs code it displays as 1st Image.

Comment: The second thing is how do I give Item height as per different device aspect ratios.

Comment: refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72514946/13997210) answer

Comment: for (1), i mean if you are using hotreload to correct your app, after you close the app and close the debug session. when you open your app again, it is using the old source instead of the latest one. the suggestion i wrote is want to ensure not because of this, since this situation is not normal for the app which is testing on the same device.
for (2), if you are aware of the different screen size, you may either use media query to calculate height or may take a look with this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil

Comment: @Cbl You are right when I uninstall and again install I didn't get this error. So recommended to you please give and in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL, I write it here. Hot reload is working by injecting new, changed source code to the Dart VM which only works when debugging. So after you killed the app or closed the debug session, the VM is down. The only thing you left is the version you **first installed when you start debug session**. That's why when you reopen it after debug closed, the app is still showing the old error version.

If you want to test it without debug session, you may either

(1) build a release version

(2) just close the debug session and start the debug session again, then the app installed should be the latest version

[Ref about hot reload in flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/hot-reload)

Answer (score 1):

> use custom SliverGridDelegate for get what you want

```
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCountAndFixedHeight
extends SliverGridDelegate {

 const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCountAndFixedHeight({
required this.crossAxisCount,
this.mainAxisSpacing = 0.0,
this.crossAxisSpacing = 0.0,
this.height = 56.0,
 })  : assert(crossAxisCount != null && crossAxisCount > 0),
    assert(mainAxisSpacing != null && mainAxisSpacing >= 0),
    assert(crossAxisSpacing != null && crossAxisSpacing >= 0),
    assert(height != null && height > 0);

final int crossAxisCount;
final double mainAxisSpacing;
final double crossAxisSpacing;
final double height;

  bool _debugAssertIsValid() {
  assert(crossAxisCount > 0);
  assert(mainAxisSpacing >= 0.0);
  assert(crossAxisSpacing >= 0.0);
  assert(height > 0.0);
  return true;
}

@override
SliverGridLayout getLayout(SliverConstraints constraints) {
assert(_debugAssertIsValid());
final double usableCrossAxisExtent =
    constraints.crossAxisExtent - crossAxisSpacing * (crossAxisCount - 1);
final double childCrossAxisExtent = usableCrossAxisExtent / crossAxisCount;
final double childMainAxisExtent = height;
return SliverGridRegularTileLayout(
  crossAxisCount: crossAxisCount,
  mainAxisStride: childMainAxisExtent + mainAxisSpacing,
  crossAxisStride: childCrossAxisExtent + crossAxisSpacing,
  childMainAxisExtent: childMainAxisExtent,
  childCrossAxisExtent: childCrossAxisExtent,
  reverseCrossAxis: axisDirectionIsReversed(constraints.crossAxisDirection),
);
 }

 @override
 bool shouldRelayout(
  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCountAndFixedHeight oldDelegate) {
  return oldDelegate.crossAxisCount != crossAxisCount ||
    oldDelegate.mainAxisSpacing != mainAxisSpacing ||
    oldDelegate.crossAxisSpacing != crossAxisSpacing ||
    oldDelegate.height != height;
 }
 }
```

> in this delegrate you can pass gridview item height

Comment: It give same issue